# Reading ORC file in Spark with schema returns null values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, orc

I am trying to read ORC files from spark job. I have defined the below schema based on output of printSchema,

> df.printSchema():

```
root
 |-- application: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- appserver: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- buildversion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- frameworkversion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- schemaversion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sdkversion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- servertimestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- trackingversion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
```

> Schema defined

```
      StructField("application", new StructType()
        .add(StructField("appserver", StringType, false))
        .add(StructField("buildversion", StringType, true))
        .add(StructField("frameworkversion", StringType, true))
        .add(StructField("id", StringType, true))
        .add(StructField("name", StringType, true))
        .add(StructField("schemaversion", StringType, true))
        .add(StructField("sdkversion", StringType, true))
        .add(StructField("servertimestamp", StringType, true))
        .add(StructField("trackingversion", StringType, true))
        .add(StructField("version", StringType, true)),
        false)
    )
```

The Dataframe output returns null for application value.

```
val data = sparkSession
      .read
      .schema(schema)
      .orc("Data/Input/")
      .select($"*")

data
      .show(100, false)
```

When the same data is read without schema defined, it returns valid values. There are few other fields in the file and I am not defining them in schema as I am not interested in them. Could this be causing issue? Can somebody help me understand the problem here?

Comment: Take a look at this: `appserver: string (nullable = true)`, `StructField("appserver", StringType, nullable = false)` (notice the nullable difference. This is also applied to some other fields you defined. (I'm not 100% sure that this is your problem, but you said you defined your struct based on what spark has inferred, yet they're different)

Comment: I changed them to false while I was trying out different options. It does not work even with nullable=true for all the fields.

Comment: if the file has 10 fields, you'll have to define all 10 fields and then select whatever number of fields you want after it has been loaded.